# Expected values in unit tests

Tags: c#, assert, unit-testing, object-expected

I am coding some unit tests for a MVC 5 internet application.

Should I hard code the expected value in the `Assert` line of code, or calculate this value from the input values before they have changed.

Here is an example:

I have a function that subtracts the correct balance from an `Account` object where the `Account` object has a `subscriptionCostPerDay` and an `accountBalance`.

Here is the code:

```
account1.subscriptionCostPerDay = 0.99M;
account1.accountBalance = 10;
```

The function that I am testing calculates the `subscriptionCostPerDay` and subtracts this from the `accountBalance`. In the above example, the `accountBalance` should be 9.01 after the function call.

Should the `Assert` statement hard code the value of 9.01, or should the expected value be calculated from the original object values?

Here are examples of the two different types I am referring to above:

1.

```
Assert.AreEqual(9.01M, account1Balance, "Account 1 has correct account balance");
```

2.

```
decimal expectedAccount1Balance = account1.accountBalance - account1.subscriptionCostPerDay;

Assert.AreEqual(expectedAccount1Balance, account1Balance, "Account 1 has correct account balance");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I prefer the first approach.  However, this type of question is not allowed in SO.

Comment: It is a programming question. Please explain why it is not allowed.

Comment: Definitely 1 first approach. Learned from The Art of Unit Testing.

Comment: Similar question [Should unit test expected results be hardcoded?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/126653)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unit Testing has two goals:

1. Find bugs in your code when the test does not work the first time
2. Make sure your code stays correct for times to come

To achieve goal (1) your test is like proof-reading by a second person. You write the expected outcome of your test **independently** of the way you arrive at this result in your code.

Therefore it is very important, that `account1Balance` is **not** calculated by the same formula as you use in your code. Exactly this formula may be buggy and writing the test is one way to find out.

Answer (score 7):

Rule of thumb: "Expected values should not contain any logic".

1. If there's a bug in the code, and we use the same logic to calculate the expected value in the test, we are replicating the
   bug.
2. The logic calculating the expected value can be flawed, thus we end up having the bug in the test code.
3. Having readability in mind, it's easier to perceive hard-coded value.

There is a good [Roy Osherove's blog post "Two different ways to create bad logic in unit tests"](http://osherove.com/blog/2010/8/14/two-different-ways-to-create-bad-logic-in-unit-tests.html) about that